# lost connection to device error while image picking from gallery

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart

I'm making app in which i'm picking image from the gallery but when I select the image the application crashed and I got the following error..
I/Process (31766): Sending signal. PID: 31766 SIG: 9
Lost connection to device.
Exited (sigterm)

here is my image picker code from which i am picking image from the gallery and the mainfest file is decribr brlow

```
import 'dart:io';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class Crop extends StatefulWidget {
final Color color;
final File image;

  const Crop({Key key, this.color,this.image}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _CropState createState() => _CropState(color,image);
}

class _CropState extends State<Crop> {
 Color color;
 File image;

  _CropState(this.color,this.image);
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
         leading: IconButton(icon: Icon(Icons.done), onPressed: (){}),
         actions: [IconButton(icon: Icon(Icons.clear), onPressed: (){})],
        title: Center(
          child: Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(right:10.0),
            
            child: Text('CROP PHOTO',
                style: TextStyle(
                  color: Colors.white,
                  fontSize: 20,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,

                  shadows: [
                    Shadow(
                      blurRadius: 10.0,
                      color: Colors.blue,
                      offset: Offset(5.0, 5.0),
                    ),
                       
                  ],
                )),
          ),
        ),
  
        backgroundColor: Colors.cyan,
      ),
      
      bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
  type: BottomNavigationBarType.fixed,
  backgroundColor: Colors.cyan,
  selectedItemColor: Colors.white,
  unselectedItemColor: Colors.white.withOpacity(.60),
  selectedFontSize: 14,
  unselectedFontSize: 14,
  onTap: (value) { 
  },
  items: [
    BottomNavigationBarItem(
      title: Text('Crop',style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),),
      icon: Icon(Icons.crop),
    ),
    BottomNavigationBarItem(
      title: Text('Edit Text'),
      icon: Icon(Icons.text_fields),
    ),
  ],
),
      body: Container(
        height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
        width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          gradient: LinearGradient(
              begin: Alignment.topRight,
              end: Alignment.bottomLeft,
              colors: [Colors.cyan[300], Colors.purple]),
        ),
child: Column(
  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
  children: [
    Container(
      height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height/2,
      width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
      color:color,
      child: Image.file(image,height:40,width:100),
    ),
  ],
),
     ),
    );
  }
}
```

here is my manfiest file code

```
    <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.bravemindstudio.invitation_card_maker">
    <!-- io.flutter.app.FlutterApplication is an android.app.Application that
         calls FlutterMain.startInitialization(this); in its onCreate method.
         In most cases you can leave this as-is, but you if you want to provide
         additional functionality it is fine to subclass or reimplement
         FlutterApplication and put your custom class here. -->


<uses-permission android:name="android:permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android:permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FILE_LOCATION" />



    <application
        android:name="io.flutter.app.FlutterApplication"
        android:label="invitation_card_maker"
        android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher">
        
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:launchMode="singleTop"
            android:theme="@style/LaunchTheme"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|locale|layoutDirection|fontScale|screenLayout|density|uiMode"
            android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
            <!-- Specifies an Android theme to apply to this Activity as soon as
                 the Android process has started. This theme is visible to the user
                 while the Flutter UI initializes. After that, this theme continues
                 to determine the Window background behind the Flutter UI. -->
            <meta-data
              android:name="io.flutter.embedding.android.NormalTheme"
              android:resource="@style/NormalTheme"
              />
            <!-- Displays an Android View that continues showing the launch screen
                 Drawable until Flutter paints its first frame, then this splash
                 screen fades out. A splash screen is useful to avoid any visual
                 gap between the end of Android's launch screen and the painting of
                 Flutter's first frame. -->
            <meta-data
              android:name="io.flutter.embedding.android.SplashScreenDrawable"
              android:resource="@drawable/launch_background"
              />
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

         <activity
    android:name="com.yalantis.ucrop.UCropActivity"
    android:screenOrientation="portrait"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar"/>
        <!-- Don't delete the meta-data below.
             This is used by the Flutter tool to generate GeneratedPluginRegistrant.java -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="flutterEmbedding"
            android:value="2" />
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Comment: post your logcat errors

Comment: It have probably something to do with application crash. Either it is due to permission issue, or memory issue or while calling for the picker you are trying to access an uninitialized view. Check for these in same order.

Comment: E/AndroidRuntime(17367):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1075)
E/AndroidRuntime(17367): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Received image from picker that was not requested
E/AndroidRuntime(17367):  at io.flutter.plugins.imagepickersaver.ImagePickerDelegate.handleImageResult(ImagePickerDelegate.java:495)

Answer (score 1):

There is image picker and image cropper library available which makes these tasks easy
[image picker](https://pub.dev/packages/image_picker)

[image cropper](https://pub.dev/packages/image_cropper)

you can call this function to pick image from gallery

```
  Future _scanBytesFromGallery() async {
PickedFile pickedFilefile = await ImagePicker().getImage(
    source: ImageSource.gallery,
    imageQuality: 50,
    maxWidth: 300,
    maxHeight: 300);
_cropImage(pickedFilefile.path);
```

}

```
 _cropImage(filePath) async {
File croppedImage = await ImageCropper.cropImage(
    sourcePath: filePath,
    aspectRatioPresets: [
      CropAspectRatioPreset.square,
      CropAspectRatioPreset.ratio3x2,
      CropAspectRatioPreset.original,
      CropAspectRatioPreset.ratio4x3,
      CropAspectRatioPreset.ratio16x9
    ],
    compressFormat: ImageCompressFormat.jpg,

    androidUiSettings: AndroidUiSettings(
      toolbarColor: Colors.blueAccent,
      toolbarWidgetColor: Colors.white,
      toolbarTitle: "CROP",
      statusBarColor: Colors.blueAccent[900],
      initAspectRatio: CropAspectRatioPreset.original,
      lockAspectRatio: false,
    ),
    iosUiSettings: IOSUiSettings(
      minimumAspectRatio: 1.0,
    ));
imageFile = croppedImage;
imgsize = await imageFile.length();
setState(() {});
```

}

Comment: Thank you soo much all

Comment: @RudeGal it it helped you please upvote the answer